# Quickbooks PHP SDK Integration

Tags: quickbooks

Can anyone Plese help me regarding the Quickbook API integration
I have downloaded SDK from
**https://majorapi.com/developers/quickbooks/sdk/php**

I have installed it and configured the keys.

I've got some db tables when executing the Quickbook.php file.

I'm stuck there, can anyone please help me further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>**If you're building a SaaS app (allowing other people to connect their QuickBooks companies to your app):**</strike>

**If you're building for QuickBooks ONLINE:**

Instead of using that lib, use the [QuickBooks PHP DevKit](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php) that's available on GitHub. It's open-source and well supported, and works fine with OAuth and v3.

You can follow the [QuickBooks PHP IPP v3 Quick-Start Guide](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QuickBooks_PHP_DevKit_for_Intuit_Anywhere) to get started. You'll go through a similar process to what you went through above, where you'll find in your own OAuth token/secret and app token in the configuration, and then you'll be able to connect to QuickBooks.

From there, you'll find several example scripts:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/example_app_ipp_v3/

<strike>**If you're building something else (something internal or for use only by a single company):**</strike>

**If you're building for QuickBooks for WINDOWS:**

Here is a [PHP QuickBooks Library](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php) which does exactly what you want to do.

You should follow the [QuickBooks PHP Web Connector quick-start guide](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Quick-Start) to get started. You'll want to architect your application so that your PHP script can receive the data, store it temporarily in a database (MySQL, etc.) and then the Web Connector can pick up the data destined for QuickBooks from there.

The Web Connector is a little different than a standard web service in that it works in a sort of backwards manner - the Web Connector will call out to *your PHP web service* vs. you calling out to it.

There's a [overview of how the Web Connector works over here](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_web_connector).

You should refer to these scripts (as the quick-start guide does above):

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/tree/master/docs/example_app_web_connector

Comment: Thanks Keith. I will follow as you said..! Thanks again..!